# The method runOnUpdateThread of AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

Do not know how to use the method runOnUpdateThread of AndEngine in the work and how to use well?Now I need some help because I do not find useful information for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method is used when you want to remove sprites or other objects from a scene mostly. It carries out what ever is within the inner `run()`on each tick or loop of the game engine. According to the creator it is for 'safe removing of objects' which will not lock up the device during execution.

**For example** you have 37 object in your scene, if you remove 1 it will be removed right away, leaving 36 objects. When the game engine cycle loops it expects 37 objects to be updated but since you removed one before the cycle ran it crashes, as it expected to update the 37th object.

Comment: Thank you! If I want to create a sprite in my scene, should I need to use this method?Because this method is safe actually.

Comment: Not unless you want it to be added from another thread, but adding a sprite is fine without it, just when you remove a sprite it happens before the game update cycle happens and then it causes errors in the engine.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know how to use it well!

Comment: Ok! The method runOnUIThread is actually update the UI in the game,should I need to use this method in updating the UI any time in my game?

Comment: runOnUiThread is the same as native android implementation, this is not synced with the upDateThread method and will cause the same crashes. You do not need to use this method when handling game objects